# Refreshing external data (from SQL Server) in org chart in Visio

Tags: sql-server, office365, visio

I have linked SQL Server employee data to create an org chart in Visio, but I can't figure out how to refresh the data in the org chart - for example if a new employee is added for this to automatically appear in the org chart, or if there is a change in title for an existing employee for this to update automatically.

[image]

I have tried the "Refresh All" under "Data" this didn't work. It refreshes the "external data" that appears on the side (which is what is linked from the SQL Server), however not the data in the actual org chart image.

Any suggestions on how to get this to properly link would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Organization Chart Wizard` in Visio, to create Organization chart using datasource.

> File tab, point to New, click Organization Chart, choose Metric Units
>   or US Units and then click Create.

In the wizard, You can choose to create a organization chart from existing data source. You can create from excel file or any ODBC compliant source. [Read more](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/create-a-visio-organization-chart-abb3dd17-2692-439f-9945-3a015767d96a)

> When you refresh report, it only updates the existing shapes. If you
>   want to add/remove shapes, you have regenerate report.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. It appears from this that only existing nodes in the org chart will have their details updated by refreshing data. What I would like is for nodes to be added or deleted automatically when there are new starters joining, or people leaving the organisation based on data that is added or removed from the SQL Server.
Is there any way to connect the nodes in such a way?